# Issue with a mysql query where (IN) - ' and "

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with a sql query.
The query works until I add the third line :`AND procurements.activity1 IN("'.$arr.'")'`.
I guess the `'` and `"` are not properly set.

`IN $arr` is an array..

Security checks are not an issue here, they are being dealt with.

My question is all about the `IN("'.$arr.'")'` line, really.

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

```
if (isset($_GET['continent'])) {$requete= 'countries.region = "'.$continent.'"';}
if (isset($_GET['pays'])) {$requete=''.$requete.' AND countries.code_iso="'.$pays.'"';}
if (isset($_GET['activity1'])) {$requete=''.$requete.' AND procurements.activity1 IN("'.$arr.'")';}
if (isset($_GET['type_org'])) {$requete=''.$requete.' AND organisations.type_org="'.$type_org.'"';}


$query = $mysqli->query('SELECT 
        countries.code_iso,
        countries.region,
        countries.fr,
        countries.en,
        countries.flag,
        procurements.id,
        procurements.ref_org,
        procurements.ref_bid,
        procurements.activity1,
        procurements.url,
        procurements.code_cpv,
        procurements.date_entered,
        procurements.date_expire,
        procurements.country_exec,
        organisations.ref_org,
        organisations.name_organisation,
        organisations.type_org,
        organisations.cp,
        organisations.city,
        organisations.country
        FROM countries, procurements, organisations
        WHERE countries.code_iso = procurements.country_exec
        AND organisations.ref_org = procurements.ref_org
        AND '.$requete.'');
```

Comment: You cannot use array. Use implode to create comma separated string from array.

Comment: $arr = implode(',', $_GET['activity1']);

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to append something you your variable instead of this:

```
$requete=''.$requete.'
```

use `$requete .= ' AND countries.code_iso="'.$pays.'"';`..

About your `IN("'.$arr.'")'`, if `$arr` is an `php array` then you cannot assign it to your `query` like that, instead use use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to combine your array into a string..

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem appears to be that you are trying to just concat in an array. However from your comment this is not the case.

However you state you use:-

```
$arr = implode(',', $_GET['activity1']);
```

But with your code of:-

```
if (isset($_GET['activity1'])) {$requete=''.$requete.' AND procurements.activity1 IN("'.$arr.'")';}
```

you would land up with something like:-

```
AND procurements.activity1 IN("1,2,3")
```

Either change

```
$arr = implode(',', $_GET['activity1']);
```

to

```
$arr = implode('","', $_GET['activity1']);
```

or change

```
if (isset($_GET['activity1'])) {$requete=''.$requete.' AND procurements.activity1 IN("'.$arr.'")';}
```

to

```
if (isset($_GET['activity1'])) {$requete=''.$requete.' AND procurements.activity1 IN('.$arr.')';}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$requete = '';

if (isset($_GET['continent'])) {$requete = ' AND countries.region = "'.$continent.'"';}
if (isset($_GET['pays'])) {$requete .=' AND countries.code_iso="'.$pays.'"';}
if (isset($_GET['activity1'])) {$requete .=' AND procurements.activity1 IN("'.implode(',',$arr).'")';}
if (isset($_GET['type_org'])) {$requete .=' AND organisations.type_org="'.$type_org.'"';}
```

and in query remove "AND"  before  $requete variable

Comment: thanks, it's working now. But I'm just wondering why I have so few results (ex: 2 records instead of 9 for a given dataset).

Comment: In mysql, the datatype of "activity1" is smallint(5). Should be correct. The country returned is OK, but I have many more records to be returned for that country. I checked in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You need to echo your sql query and run into phpmyadmin.

Comment: You check in your sql query which fields are present in conditions, and if they satisfy or not according to that result will shown.